# I receive strange characters in Android from bluetooth connected to Arduino

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arduino

Arduino receives the data without a problem, but when I receive android data from an arduino via bluetooth, strange characters appear such as . Here is the method code that receives the data:

```
private String convertInputToString() throws IOException {

    DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(btSocket.getInputStream());

    char c;
    String s = "";

    do {
        c = (char) is.read();
        s += c + "";
    } while (c != '\n');

    return s;
}
```

And I transmit the arduino data with Serial.println

I use Arduino Uno and Bluetoot HC-06

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [DataInputStream](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/DataInputStream) from Android Developer Guide in detail.

The Input and Output Streams deal in pure bytes,

Android also provides methods to read chunks of bytes and create standard data types.

The right way to get data is:

`byte[] readStream = new byte[LENGTH];
int howManyBytesInStream;
howManyBytesInStream = is.read(readStream);`

The data you need is stored in **readStream**, and

**howManyBytesInStream** is the number of bytes you actually read.

Comment: how do I know exactly what value to assign to LENGTH?

Comment: It will depend upon the length of data packets you are dealing with, you can cap them with the length of the biggest packet.
I use 1024 and all the messages I deal with are smaller than this length.